# iPad - How do I load the first cell from the RootView automatically into the DetailView upon launch?

Tags: ipad, ios, uitableview, rootview

The title pretty much asks it all. I've been coming back and trying to implement this every few days, but I cant seem to get it to work. I'd assume the code to set the detailItem from launch goes in the viewDidLoad, but at this point I am clueless.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

--Tyler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `selectRowAtIndexPath` delegate:

```
[tblMyTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
```

Of course, replace `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]` with the section / row that you want to automatically set.

You can either put this in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` delegate.

Also, make sure that you define your `tblMyTable` *(or whatever you have named your table)* in your header, hooked it up through Interface Builder *(if your using a custom XIB)*, and use `@synthesize` in your **.m**

And the `didSelectRowAtIndex:` should be called when you use that method, so as long as your detailItem code is in `didSelectRowAtIndex`, you should be good.

Comment: What would the tblMyTable be if I am using the prebuilt table of the RootViewController? I've tried synthesizing the tableView from the TableViewContoller to use it, but I get "UITableView may not respond to '-didSelectRowAtIndexPath' warning. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I got the first cell to load in the DetailView just by setting the detailItem to the objectAtIndex:0. It loads the data from the RootView just fine, but it doesn't select the cell where it's coming from in the RootView. Is there a way to select/enable a single cell without getting any of it's data (just highlight it)?

Comment: Apple frowns upon keeping the cell highlighted.

Comment: You may be able to use something like this: `[tblMyTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];`  Just make sure you have your selection style set.  I personally like to make custom colors for my tables, so I usually control the selection highlighting by changing the background color of the cell the user presses and setting the default selection type to none...